# Dexterity - initialize schema values

Tags: plone, dexterity

I've had this gotcha when creating Dexterity content programmatically, such as with invokeFactory, instead of through a form. Basically the default value for every field in the schema is going to be None instead of an empty string, an empty list, etc. If I wanted to loop through all values in a schema.List field I end up having to check if it's a list first or risk getting an error, depending on how that content was created.

I'm wondering if perhaps I am missing some method that processes all fields to set initial values if they're not already defined. Perhaps invokeFactory is not the preferred method? Would it be bad practice to have an event listener for created Dexterity content that sets initial values?

Answer (score 2):

What you're missing is the `default` property every Dexterity-based content type have on the definition of its schema fields.

See [Field properties](http://docs.plone.org/external/plone.app.dexterity/docs/reference/fields.html) on the Dexterity Developer Manual.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, thanks! To be honest I had only been using @form.default_value decorators and forgot this attribute even existed.

Answer (score 1):

Try createObject or createContent, followed by adding the object to a container.

These are both documented in [Manipulating content objects](http://docs.plone.org/external/plone.app.dexterity/docs/reference/manipulating-content-objects.html) in the reference section of the Dexterity manual. It has all the imports and example code.

Answer (score 1):

Experience teached me to always initialize my schemas filing the `default` and `missing_value` optional parameters, e.g.:

```
name = schema.TextLine(
    title=u'Name',
    default=u'',
    missing_value=u'',
)
colors = schema.List(
    title=_('Colors'),
    value_type=schema.TextLine(),
    default=[],
    missing_value=[],
)
```

The reason is that `default` is needed when you create the object programmatically (e.g. using `plone.api.content.create`) and do not initialize the relevant property, while `missing_value` is needed when you do not pass any value to a z3c.form.